# Есть ли разница при SELECT * или SELECT `some_column` в PHP

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, select, производительность

Интересует насколько это влияет на производительность запроса в PHP

все запросы я делаю просто `SELECT * ... LIMIT 0,20` и он постоянно подтягивает значения всех столбцов (их примерно до 15), но использую из них я максимум 6-7.

У меня все время стоит лимит, а в базе строк больше > 10000 вот интересно это сильно влияет на скорость? а что если дальше продолжать еще делать JOIN'ы ?

Comment: Старайтесь всегда запрашивать только то, что необходимо. На сколько сильно трудно сказать. Зависит от мощности и загруженности сервера.  В принципе для современных серверов это не нагрузка. Но это не повод ставить всегда звездочку.

Comment: выбираете через звездочку, тогда хотя бы делайте table1.*, table2.*.

Comment: когда  в таблице окажутся бинарные поля с данными, тогда и получите сюрприз. Получите что с 3мя строками результата надо передать клиенту к примеру 200метров данных (картинки, пдф, видео и т.п.).

Comment: Если  суммарный объём нужных полей равен суммарному объёму ненужных - ответ от сервера будет передаваться на клиента вдвое дольше. Более в обычных условиях никакого влияния не будет. Однако если все нужные поля могут быть получены из покрывающего индекса, то в этом случае можно получить заметную разницу в производительности - при указании конкретных полей серверу не придётся лезть в таблицу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В большинстве случаев морочиться на эту тему не нужно. Вопрос про * в запросах - это такая trivia, которую нубы с придыханием рассказывают друг другу и которую можно прочитать в идиотских списках "25 способов ускорить свой скрипт в 100500 раз".

Если удобно писать * и в базе нет блобов с гигазами варезов, а есть 15 несчастных варчаров, то никто не умрет от звездочки.

**Плюсы использования звездочки:**

- при добавлении полей в таблицу не надо менять код запроса
- запрос становится читабельнее и короче

**Минусы использования звездочки:**

- большой потенциальный объем данных, передаваемых в пхп, может сказаться на производительности
- если в запросе используется **временная таблица**, то наличие ненужных полей может катастрофически отразиться на времени запроса, поскольку во временную таблицу будут записываться все поля таблицы. Разумеется, лучше избегать запросов, которым требуется создание временной таблицы.

Comment: если в запросе есть джойны, всё таки лучше выбрать нужные поля) иначе придёт всё, или хотя бы table.* указать

Comment: Ну если в джойне те же 15 варчаров, то ничего страшного :) Реальные проблемы с проивзодительностью редко вызываются звездочкой в запросе. Как правильно ждделает автор - куда полезнее писать лимит.

Comment: про лимит не спорю, но если в будущем добавят блоб в одну из таблиц - будет проблема из-за звёздочки)

Comment: Ну так и не надо добавлять блобы в БД. им там совершенно нечего делать

Comment: Задачи разные бывают)) кто знает что добавится.

Answer (score 0):

использование * = "bad practice". 
минусы использование * :
1)если вы будете дальнейшей писать JOIN-i тогда  у вас будет проблемы
2)если вы будете дальнейшей добавляет столбцы тогда они будет автоматический подключиться "без нужды"
3)лишние данные это зло
4)использование не дает вам прав наименование столбцов
5)может быть меньше но влияет на загрузку